# Set Array of Object return empty array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

I am really stuck here. Please help!

I have an array like this:

```
0:{
area: {acres: "249,561.00", square_km: "1,009.9"}
coordinates: {latitude: 34.01, longitude: -119.42}
id: "park_channel-islands"
title: "Channel Islands"
visitors: "364,807}
1: {area: {…}, coordinates: {…}, date_established_readable...
2: .....
3: ....
```

This is my state in constructor `this.state ={coodLabell:[]}`

I want to fill up the array coordinators by creating the object of the field coordinates and field title in the array.

For example: in the index 0 . I want to create the object {"title": title, "cood": coordinates" and push it into the empty array coordinators I have in the constructors.

This is what I tried but I always got back the empty array

```
  array.forEach((element) => {
            const title = element.title
            const cood = element.coordinates
            const  newData = {"title": title, "cood": cood}

            this.setState({coodLabell:[...this.state.coodLabell,...newData]})
```

I appreciate if you guys can give me some hints. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work, you need to create an array and combine it with current state after foreach.

```
let newArray = []
    array.forEach((element) => {
      const title = element.title
      const cood = element.coordinates
      const newData = { "title": title, "cood": cood };
      newArray.push(newData);
    })
  this.setState({ coodLabell: [...this.state.coodLabell, ...newArray] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const  newData = {"title": title, "cood": cood}
let Data = this.state.coodLabell.push(newData)
this.setState({coodLabell:Data})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I get it you wanna have only 2 properties (`title` and `coordinates`) of the original object and get rid of the others.

In this case you have to map you array, like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    area: { acres: '249,561.00', square_km: '1,009.9' },
    coordinates: { latitude: 34.01, longitude: -119.42 },
    id: 'park_channel-islands',
    title: 'Channel Islands',
    visitors: '364,807',
  },
  {
    area: { acres: '249,561.00', square_km: '1,009.9' },
    coordinates: { latitude: 20.01, longitude: -100.42 },
    id: 'park_channel-islands',
    title: 'Abc',
    visitors: '364,807',
  },
  {
    area: { acres: '249,561.00', square_km: '1,009.9' },
    coordinates: { latitude: 10.01, longitude: -50.42 },
    id: 'park_channel-islands',
    title: 'Xyz',
    visitors: '364,807',
  },
];

const filteredData = data.map(({title, coordinates}) => ({title, coordinates}))

console.log({filteredData})

// and here you can
// this.setState({ anything: filteredData })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
const coodLabell = Object.values(yourData).map(element => {
    return {
      "title": element.title,
      "cood": element.coordinates
    }
});
this.setState({ coodLabell })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [coodLabell, setCoodLabell] = useState({});

const array = [
  {
    area: {acres: "249,561.00", square_km: "1,009.9"}
    coordinates: {latitude: 34.01, longitude: -119.42}
    id: "park_channel-islands"
    title: "Channel Islands"
    visitors: "364,807
  },
  {....},
  {....},
  {....},
];

let coodLabell = array.map(item => {
   return {
     title: item.title,
     cood: item.coordinates
   }
})

setCoodLabell(coodLabell)
```